# How to find this word 'অশুভ' in my string using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, nlp, wordnet

I am trying to find this word using regular expression. But the issue I found is whenever I tried using word border "\b" it doesn't work accurately. 
And if I didn't use any RegEx then it will show different output where it has been used like 'অশুভৰ' 'অশুভ_লক্ষণ'.  I want to eliminate these results and only want that word precisely.

This is the string: "মেকুৰীয়ে ৰাস্তা কাটিলে অশুভ বুলি ধৰা হয়, দুৱাৰডলিত বহাটো অশুভনীয়, যি লক্ষণ অশুভৰ পৰিচায়ক"

Comment: Can you show the complete regex (and calling code) you used? `r'\b'` on its own won't match a lot.

Comment: The point is that `\b` only matches between word and a non-word char, at the start of the string before a word char and at the end of the string after a word char, BUT diacritics are not word chars. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of `\b` as just shortcut for defining your own set of boundary conditions. I've shown below how to use `\b`, then how to use an explicit space, then how to do the same but with lookbehind/lookahead assertions.

The difference between the last two approaches is that `[ ]` will capture the spaces either side, while the assertions (and `\b`) will not. (You can see this in the sample output, below.)

You can also see below that `\b` works fine on the two test cases you gave. But I assume you are using it in more complicated strings, or in more complicated regexes?

```
import re

s1="মেকুৰীয়ে ৰাস্তা কাটিলে অশুভ বুলি ধৰা হয়, দুৱাৰডলিত বহাটো অশুভনীয়, যি লক্ষণ অশুভৰ পৰিচায়ক"
s2 = "অশুভৰ অশুভ_লক্ষণ"

pat = r'অশুভ'
m = re.search(pat,s1)
print(m)
m = re.search(pat,s2)
print(m)

pat = r'\bঅশুভ\b'
m = re.search(pat,s1)
print(m)
m = re.search(pat,s2)
print(m)

pat = r'[ ]অশুভ[ ]'
m = re.search(pat,s1)
print(m)
m = re.search(pat,s2)
print(m)

pat = r'(?<= )অশুভ(?= )'
m = re.search(pat,s1)
print(m)
m = re.search(pat,s2)
print(m)
```

Output (python 3.6):

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(23, 27), match='অশুভ'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='অশুভ'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(23, 27), match='অশুভ'>
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(22, 28), match=' অশুভ '>
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(23, 27), match='অশুভ'>
None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use index to find the word.

```
>>> s="মেকুৰীয়ে ৰাস্তা কাটিলে অশুভ বুলি ধৰা হয়, দুৱাৰডলিত বহাটো অশুভনীয়, যি লক্ষণ অশুভৰ পৰিচায়ক"
>>> s.index("অশুভ")
23
```

Comment: They don't want অশুভ to match in ` 'অশুভৰ' 'অশুভ_লক্ষণ'` though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that with the `in` keyword.

```
>>> s = "মেকুৰীয়ে ৰাস্তা কাটিলে অশুভ বুলি ধৰা হয়, দুৱাৰডলিত বহাটো অশুভনীয়, যি লক্ষণ অশুভৰ পৰিচায়ক"
>>> "অশুভৰ" in s
True
>>> "অভ" in s
False
```

Comment: I think the asker is looking for a solution that will return the location the word appears in the text. Where, not if.

Comment: They don't want অশুভ to match in ` 'অশুভৰ' 'অশুভ_লক্ষণ'` though.